# Using conditional block in RazorEngine.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parsing, c#-4.0, razor

I am using razorEngine.dll to parse my email templates to parse business objects. It has been working great so far. I also want to be able to do something like @if block with razor engine.

I know MVC Razor view can do it but I am not sure if razorengine.dll is capable of doing it.

I have following code which throw error. may be I am not going great with the syntax. The documentation on RazorEngine.dll does not say anything about conditional block.

I have tried something like following which throws parsing error:

```
const string template = "<html>Welcome, your answer is @if(Model.User.Qualified){Congratualtions}</html>";
            dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();
            model.User = new
                             {
                                 Qualified = true
                             };
            var body = uut.RenderTemplate(template, model);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The `Congratulations` word is within the `if` block.  The razor engine thinks it is a piece of code - thus a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, you are correct when I emptied out the if block, it is not throwing error but the problem is that I want it to output Congratulations if Qualified == true and "I am sorry" otherwise. If i can not have simple text in then how can I achieve it? Do I have to have both text messages as part of the @Model ?

Comment: I believe `@<text>Congratulations</text>` should do the trick.  But that's untested.

Comment: actually,{<p>Congratulations</p>} did the trick. Thank you so much :)